# How a control-statement, array, function (procedure) is compiled by a simple compiler?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, compilation, conditional-compilation

I just want to know a simple explanation of how if-else statements, loops, procedures get parsed by a compiler ?

I found it ungoogleable..... :( Please Help me to get into this...!!!

Comment: _parsing_ and _compiling_ are very different tasks.  What precisely are you asking about?

Comment: i think parsing is one of the different stages of compilation. @SLaks

Comment: Correct. (as opposed to code-gen) What precisely are you asking about?

Comment: i want simple explanation of how a compiler parses a control statement , array etc ? Simple theory and examples !

Comment: The same way it parses any other block or expression.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing

Comment: I already hit it... thanx @SLaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing is a fairly large and somewhat complicated subject.  If you're familiar with Python, the Pyparsing module might be a good place to start.  It's not a parser itself, but sort of a parser generator.

Some other well-known parser generators are ANTLR and Lex/Yacc.  Pyparsing is simpler (if slower), and it accepts the well-known BNF as its description language.  Check out the examples below.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/tree/master/examples

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing